# Prism with Xamarin for Android - InvalidOperationException on Launch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, unity-container, prism

I'm new to Xamarin and Prism, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. I am following the example of [this project in GitHub](https://github.com/DanielCauser/SocialLoginSamples/tree/master/FacebookNativeLogin/FacebookNativeLogin). However, I am getting the following error when running my Android project.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The current type, MyApp.Abstractions.IFacebookManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

The error is occurring in `EntryPage.xaml.g.cs` in the `LoadFromXaml()` method.

```
[global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("Views\\EntryPage.xaml")]
public partial class EntryPage : global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage {

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        // Exception thrown here!
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(EntryPage));
    }
}
```

This leads me to believe that I'm not using the IoC container properly, but I can't see what I'm doing differently from the example. The `EntryPageViewModel`'s constructor takes `IFacebookManager` as a parameter and I understand that Unity should take care of this. I have a breakpoint on the constructor, but it's not being hit. This is a .NET Standard Xamarin solution. I would appreciate any help and guidance. Thank you!

Here's my `App.xaml.cs`

```
using MyApp.Abstractions;
using MyApp.Helpers;
using MyApp.Services;
using MyApp.ViewModels;
using MyApp.Views;
using Prism;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Unity;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }


        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ServiceResolver.Instance.Add<ICloudService, AzureCloudService>();

            NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/EntryPage");            
        }



        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<EntryPage, EntryPageViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my `MainActivity.cs`

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using MyApp.Droid.Services;
using MyApp.Abstractions;
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Facebook;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Prism;
using Prism.Ioc;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", Name = "com.mydomain.myapp.MainActivity", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        ICallbackManager fbCallbackManager;
        AndroidLoginProvider loginProvider;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();                        
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            DependencyService.Register<IFacebookManager, FacebookManager>();

            LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            var manager = DependencyService.Get<IFacebookManager>();
            if (manager != null)
            {
                (manager as FacebookManager)._callbackManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, (int)resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }

    public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
    {
        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
        }
    }
}



public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the Xamarin Forms [Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) with the one provided with [Prism.Unity](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Unity.Forms)

Instead of calling `DependencyService.Register<IFacebookManager, FacebookManager>();`

You need to register it with the `AndroidInitializer` .

```
public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry container)
    {
        container.RegisterSingleton<IFacebookManager, FacebookManager>();
    }
}
```

You can then always resolve a dependency manually by calling `App.Container.Resolve` inside `OnActivityResult`.

Comment: I had thought of that, but was trying to follow the example. Anyway, this approach seems good, but I cannot call `App.Container.Resolve<IFacebookManager>()` because I get the error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PrismApplicationBase.Container.'` I'm guessing that `App` here needs to be a reference to an instance of the `App` class, not a reference to the class itself. Is there a clean way of getting a reference to the current App instance from my Android project?

Comment: @NSouth Yep you can call ((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current).Container.Resolve()

Comment: I should point out here that Prism 7.1 which has the ContainerProvider<T> for resolving types in XAML, also overrides the static Current property so you could do `App.Current.Container.Resolve<T>()`. Also you should not be using a ServiceLocator or the XF Dependency Service as it creates an anti-pattern with multiple containers.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the previous answer that helped me a lot to fix a similar issue:
with prism 7, you need to resolve a dependency via `IContainerProvider` as follow:

```
var container = (App.Current as Prism.Unity.PrismApplication).Container;
var manager = container.Resolve<IFacebookManager>();
```

In this case, Unity is used as the IoC "container"

Comment: Is there something as "generic" container?

Comment: Sorry could you explain your question I do not see what you mean

Comment: Instead of specifying which `IoC` namespace I will be using, is there something like: (App.Current as Prism. **Generic** .PrismApplication).Container?

Comment: I would say no you can't. But note that now, probably because of a new Prism version (7.1) you can get your container like that: `container=PrismApplicationBase.Current.Container;` This allows you to get it without specifying which IoC you will use.

Comment: Great! Thanks for this info :)
I wish they would include that in their release notes.